# Request for account deletion

Tags: support

I recently sent two requests to have my account deleted using this contact form https://math.stackexchange.com/contact as suggested in the help page for user deletion, but I haven't received any responses so far.

With that said, if you're a mod passing by (or someone with the power to delete accounts), can someone help manually delete my account? Thanks

Comment: You need to put "Please delete me" in your profile

Comment: @robjohn oops, I'll do that now

Comment: I now have Engelbert Humperdinck going round in my head: "Please delete me, let me go, For I don't love you anymore. To waste our lives would be a sin, Release me and let me (do badass maths) again."

Comment: @pleasedeleteme: I am asking the community team whether you need to resubmit via the "contact us" link. When did you first request your account be deleted?

Comment: @robjohn Thanks- I sent the requests yesterday

Comment: @pleasedeleteme: the powers that be say to wait until the scripts that implement the deletions run (around 3:00 UTC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is *usually* automated. You should receive a response within 24 hours of your request, at which point your account will be deleted once another 24 hours passes (although you can cancel the request within this time-period if you wish).

If anything goes wrong, the system will escalate it to a real person who will then respond or remove (depending on the exact nature of your request) as they have time to do so.

Currently, your account is scheduled for removal, which you should be able to observe by visiting [your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current). If you do nothing, it will be removed within 24 hours.

Comment: Oh... And I'm not entirely sure what it's gonna do when it finds your *second* request in an hour; might do nothing, might restart the timer. This is all pretty new... You're a pioneer!